# Firebase android ordering

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm unable to order result with orderByChild on a date field (timestamp)

Here the structure of data :

[image]

And the code :

```
  DatabaseReference mMessagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages")
                .child(mConversationId).getRef()
                .orderByChild("date").getRef();
        mMessagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
```

The query returned the value, but not ordered by date, it's return by key..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Try this:
DatabaseReference mMessagesRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query queryRef = mMessagesRef.child("messages").orderByChild("date");
queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
```